# writing Character array in a file in C

Tags: c

I want to write a character array   `char array="some text"`  in a file what is the easiest way to write this in `C`.Actually i am writing a device driver so i have to write code in C for Device driver.And from user space i have to read an array of characters from user space and also write a character array in kernel space but i am new to C so that's why i was asking  this question.

Comment: Maybe `char array[]="some text";`

Comment: no this way is initializing the array i am asking to write a character array in a file.Do you understand what i am asking?

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib Your question is wrong. it should be `char array[]` not `char array`. Thats what the comment about yours is suggesting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Char arrays are declared like so:
char array[] = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

// Open a file for writing. 
// (This will replace any existing file. Use "w+" for appending)
FILE *file = fopen("filename", "w");

int results = fputs(array, file);
if (results == EOF) {
    // Failed to write do error code here.
}
fclose(file);
```

Edit:

- had the arguments of `fputs` backwards.
- `fputs` does not return number of bytes written. Just an error code.

Comment: I doubt its gonna reutrn no of bytes written

Comment: I see (after checking man page). I'll fix that.

Comment: Thanks for all especially HornetBlack. "The world is Gold if you are BOLD"

Answer (score 3):

Let's do it all on one line!

```
struct FILE* fopen(const char*, const char*); int fprintf(struct FILE*, const char*, ...); int main(int argc, char** argv) { return !fprintf(fopen("/path/to/file", "w+"), "some text");}
```

---

I swear to $DEITY, I wrote this out in the text box here, copied it into a file, and then compiled with `gcc -Wall`.  It built correctly and ran correctly, the first time.  Knowing how sloppy I usually am, this is *amazing*.

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE * file = fopen("/path/of/file","w+");
int return_val = fputs(array,file);

if (return_val >= o )
    printf("Success");

else 
    printf("failed");
```